# How can I find Flash content with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

How can I find Flash content with JavaScript?

Tools like adblockers or gimme bar seem to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash uses `<object>` and `<embed>` tags. Do a `getElementsByTagName` on those two Flash tags:

```
var flash1=document.getElementsByTagName("object");
var flash2=document.getElementsByTagName("embed");
```

Note that YouTube embeds use `<iframe>` elements, so its harder to capture those. Also, make sure you run this after all elements have loaded (a.k.a. `window.onload`), otherwise you'll miss some or all.

Comment: You can also do similar things with JQuery

Comment: True, but if this is the extent of his selections, jQuery would be mega-overkill.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this code can help:

```
<script>
var length = document.getElementsByTagName('object').length;
alert(length);
</script>
```

add your end of page..

Comment: That just determines _how many_ objects there are, and does not take in to account the older `<embed>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

**2017 answer**: A single line can find both types of Flash element:

```
document.querySelectorAll("object, embed");
```